# Duplicate Contacts in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I'm populating contact lists from device using below code, Everything seems fine but Contacts are showing twice or even more than twice, Please help base on my code. I've tried many many solutions but the code I have to fetch contact list is using Asynctasks and some other properties I am not aware of, So I need a solution based on my code below
Thanks in Advance :)

**My Activity Class below**

```
public class Contacts extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<ContactsPoJo> selectUsers;
ArrayList<Conversation> conversations;
ContactsPoJo myPOJO;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
RecyclerAdapter adapter;
Context mContext;
ProgressBar progressBar;
ConverstaionItemAdapter converstaionItemAdapter;
ProgressDialog dialog;
String[] mProjection = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME};

private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_listLog);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarLog);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
    selectUsers = new ArrayList<ContactsPoJo>();
    showContacts();
}

private void showContacts() {
    // Check the SDK version and whether the permission is already granted or not.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && 
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 
PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) 
overriden method
    } else {
        // Android version is lesser than 6.0 or the permission is already granted.
        Contacts.LoadContact loadContact = new LoadContact();
        loadContact.execute();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission is granted
            showContacts();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Until you grant the permission, we canot display the names", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

class LoadContact extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // Get Contact list from Phone
        Cursor phones = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, mProjection, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(id));
            Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
            ContactsPoJo selectUser = new ContactsPoJo();
            selectUser.setName(name);
            selectUser.setPhoto(photoUri);
            selectUser.setPhone(phoneNumber);
            selectUsers.add(selectUser);
        } phones.close();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // sortContacts();
        int count=selectUsers.size();
        ArrayList<ContactsPoJo> removed=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ContactsPoJo> contacts=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<selectUsers.size();i++){
            ContactsPoJo inviteFriendsProjo = selectUsers.get(i);

            if(inviteFriendsProjo.getName().matches("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?")||inviteFriendsProjo.getName().trim().length()==0){
                removed.add(inviteFriendsProjo);
            }else{
                contacts.add(inviteFriendsProjo);
            }
        }
        contacts.addAll(removed);
        selectUsers=contacts;
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(inflater, selectUsers, getApplicationContext(), onClickListener );
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // selectUsers.add(0,  );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you've duplicate contacts on phone .. some from the device, and others grabbed by the device from the archived Google account .. can you check it

Comment: Every single user would have at least one duplicate contact in their device, So I can I show contacts once only?

Comment: Not sure if you can grab contacts from other archives.. you can verify this by comparing the `RecyclerView` list to the contacts list on the phone. If that can not be the case, please update the question so someone can look deeply on code

Comment: I've tried the code on 3 different devices, But Results are same

Comment: Look at `selectUsers` in the debugger to verify that the duplicate entries aren't there. If `selectUsers` looks OK to you then `RecyclerAdapter` will be suspect. Post that code it `selectUsers` looks OK.